# How to achieve object scoped singletons in the Unity Container?

Tags: c#, unity-container

Assume that I have the following class structure:

```
public class Outer
{
    [Dependency]
    public Func<Inner> InnerFactory { get; set; }
}

public class Inner
{
}
```

In Autofac this can be done easily in the following way (and describes the behaviour I am looking for; ignore the fact that this is a stupid contrived example):

```
[TestMethod]
public void AutofacMakesThisEasy()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<Outer>().PropertiesAutowired();
    builder.RegisterType<Inner>().InstancePerOwned<Outer>();

    var container = builder.Build();

    var outer1 = container.Resolve<Owned<Outer>>().Value;

    var inner1 = outer1.InnerFactory();
    var inner2 = outer1.InnerFactory();

    var outer2 = container.Resolve<Owned<Outer>>().Value;

    var inner3 = outer2.InnerFactory();
    var inner4 = outer2.InnerFactory();

    Assert.AreNotSame(outer1, outer2, "outer1 == outer2");
    Assert.AreSame(inner1, inner2, "inner1 != inner2");
    Assert.AreNotSame(inner2, inner3, "inner2 == inner3");
    Assert.AreSame(inner3, inner4, "inner3 != inner4");
}
```

How can I achieve the same behaviour in unity so the following test passes?

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnityHasMeScratchingMyHead()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    //// What shoud I do here?

    var outer1 = container.Resolve<Outer>();

    var inner1 = outer1.InnerFactory();
    var inner2 = outer1.InnerFactory();

    var outer2 = container.Resolve<Outer>();

    var inner3 = outer2.InnerFactory();
    var inner4 = outer2.InnerFactory();

    Assert.AreNotSame(outer1, outer2, "outer1 == outer2");
    Assert.AreSame(inner1, inner2, "inner1 != inner2");
    Assert.AreNotSame(inner2, inner3, "inner2 == inner3");
    Assert.AreSame(inner3, inner4, "inner3 != inner4");
}
```

Note: I would dearly love to ditch Unity for a decent IoC, but that is going to be a very hard sell.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is a clearly articulated question?

Comment: Something using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660895(v=pandp.20).aspx) and the [HierarchicalLifetimeManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.hierarchicallifetimemanager(v=pandp.51).aspx) might be what you want?

Comment: Two months after this I managed to make the sell and we moved to Autofac and ditched Prism for our own MVVM framework based on Caliburn, but without all of the convention based bindings (which are actually just plain confusing once you reach any sort of scale). It has worked out very well for us. I would thoroughly recommend anyone in a similar position to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

If `InnerFactory` was just `Inner` instead of `Func<Inner>` The solution would be `PerResolveLifetimeManager`

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnityHasMeScratchingMyHead()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<Inner>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());

    var outer1 = container.Resolve<Outer>();
    //... and so on.
```

However because you have a factory you need to make it a little more complicated. You need to make the factory PerResolve then have the objects the factory makes all the same instance (`ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`). You do that via the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnityHasMeScratchingMyHead()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<Func<Inner>>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(x =>
    {
        var child = x.CreateChildContainer();
        child.RegisterType<Inner>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        return new Func<Inner>(() => child.Resolve<Inner>());
    }));

    var outer1 = container.Resolve<Outer>();

    var inner1 = outer1.InnerFactory();
    var inner2 = outer1.InnerFactory();

    var outer2 = container.Resolve<Outer>();

    var inner3 = outer2.InnerFactory();
    var inner4 = outer2.InnerFactory();

    Assert.AreNotSame(outer1, outer2, "outer1 == outer2");
    Assert.AreSame(inner1, inner2, "inner1 != inner2");
    Assert.AreNotSame(inner2, inner3, "inner2 == inner3");
    Assert.AreSame(inner3, inner4, "inner3 != inner4");
}
```

One thing of note, [Unity is easily extensible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178462(v=pandp.30).aspx). If you are going to be doing this frequently with a little work you could make a `InstancePerOwnedLifetimeManager<T>` and just use that and not need to worry about generating factories at all.

Comment: Scott, thanks. I ended up pseudo replicating Autofac's Owned<> that just resolves a child container and then registering everything with HierarchicalLMs. That is just about good enough for my purposes, but isn't quite the same as Owned as it is not scoped to a particular parent object type - it just creates a new child container transparently. I did have a stab at creating my own lifetime manager, but it wasn't clear how to hook into the container since the interface itself provides no hooks into the container. Any pointers?

Comment: @briantyler Unfortunately no. I know that it can be done, but I have never tried to do it myself.

Comment: I've been browsing the (decompiled) sources and I'm starting to get an idea of how this could be done; will report back once I've cracked it.

Comment: @briantyler No need to use the decompiled sources, [Unity is open source project](https://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/Unity/Src/Lifetime/LifetimeManager.cs) by microsoft.

Comment: Yeah, its just easier to hit F12. Anyway it looks to me like this is likely very hard to achieve. I can sort of manage something which is similar enough using hierarchical lifetimes and a wrapper that spawns a new child container. I'm really quite disappointed with Unity; I'd heard it was pretty limited and had always avoided it as a result and kind of feel vindicated in that decision.